# display time of exception message magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

i need to be able to increase the standard time the error message displays when customers attempt to check out uncorrectly, currently it happens far to qiuck and customers do not see the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran in the same problem today and found your question. Don't know if you're still looking for an answer.

This time is set in `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\frontend\web\js\view\messages.js`

At the bottom you find this function where you can extend the timeout:

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
            var self = this;
            // Hide message block if needed
            if (isHidden) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500)
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
```

Since you don't want to edit core files you can overwrite this file in your theme at `app\design\frontend\[vendor]\[theme]\Magento_Ui\web\js\view\messages.js`

Comment: Thanks for this i kind of by passed this problem by creating a pop on error but this is a better solution